# Simplify $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+a)}$ with $a\in\mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

How can simplify the following expression?
$$\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+a)}\sim \cdots\text{ ?}$$
Where $a\in\mathbb C$, $n\in \mathbb N$. Any suggestions please?

> I propose the following. We have the classical Stirling's
>   approximation formula for the Gamma-Function in the form: $$  
> \Gamma(z)=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-z}z^{z-1/2}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)\right)
>  $$
>
> for $|\arg(z)|<\pi$ as $|z|\to\infty$.
>
> And, from [another question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63115/variations-on-the-stirlings-formula-for-gammaz?rq=1) there is also the shifted
>   Stirling's approximation for the Gamma-Function due to C. Rowe that
>   says: $$  
> \Gamma(z+a)=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-z}z^{z+a-1/2}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)\right)
> $$
>
> Therefore
>
> $$  
> \frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(z+a)}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-z}z^{z-1/2}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-z}z^{z+a-1/2}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)\right)}=\frac{\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)\right)}{z^a\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)\right)}
> $$ and: $$   \frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+a)}\sim n^{-a} \ \ \
> (n\rightarrow \infty) $$
>
> I would appreciate some corrections on this procedure. Thanks.

Comment: does $n \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: Now this is simple!

Comment: I'd have expected $a^{-n}$ rather than $n^{-a}$, but I haven't looked closely yet$\ldots\ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$B(n,a) = \int_{0}^{1} t^{n-1}(1-t)^{a-1} dt = \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(n + a)}$$

Where $B$ is the [Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and $\mathcal {Re} (a) > 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post. I'd like to have your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x).
$$
So
\begin{align}
\Gamma(5+a) & = (4+a)\Gamma(4+a) \\[8pt]
& = (4+a)(3+a)\Gamma(3+a) \\[8pt]
& = (4+a)(3+a)(2+a)\Gamma(2+a) \\[8pt]
& = (4+a)(3+a)(2+a)(1+a)\Gamma(1+a) \\[8pt]
& = (4+a)(3+a)(2+a)(1+a)a\Gamma(a)
\end{align}
and then cancel a factor from the numerator and denominator.  And similarly for $n\ne4$.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post. I'd like to have your opinion.